# In Java, are parameters accesses in order when passed into a method?

Tags: java, methods, parameter-passing, deserialization

This is important because I am creating an object out of deserialized primitives within the readObject method.  So if I am writing

```
ObjectInputStream s; //From the readObject method
Object obj = new Object(s.readDouble(), s.readDouble(), s.readDouble());
```

Will it deserialize in the correct order, the order they were written to the byte stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will deserialize in the correct order.

You might want to create (good) named variables out of those `s.readDouble()` values though, it's more clear what they mean.

Answer (score 3):

Yes parameters will be evaluated in order.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, expressions are always evaluated left-to-right. So the result of the first `readDouble` call will become the first argument to the `Object` constructor (but please don't name your class `Object`! that collides with `java.lang.Object`), and so on.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I just made a name up to show that I was constructing a random object.

Answer (score 1):

Java argument lists are evaluated Left-to-Right